# Android checkbox without check mark on smartphone (emulator is working)

Tags: android, checkbox, android-emulator

I have some checkboxs that don't work correctly. Checkboxs result checked but there are no check marks. If click on checkbox twice, check mark appears.
On the emulator there are no problem, but on my Galaxy S7 (Oreo) there is this bug. Checkboxs are checked programmaticaly after loading data from db:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean successo) {
        pbGestioneProfilo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (successo) {
            passioniET.setText(passioni);
            libriET.setText(libri);
            filmserieET.setText(filmserie);
            negoziET.setText(negozi);
            tecnologiaCB.setChecked(tecnologia.equals(Utils.TRUE) ? true : false);
            sportCB.setChecked(sport.equals(Utils.TRUE) ? true : false);
            viaggiCB.setChecked(viaggi.equals(Utils.TRUE) ? true : false);
            casacucinaCB.setChecked(casacucina.equals(Utils.TRUE) ? true : false);
            abbigliamentoCB.setChecked(abbigliamento.equals(Utils.TRUE) ? true : false);
            if (!urlProfilo.equals("")) {
                Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load(urlProfilo)
                        .into(imgprofilo);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("MYTAG","ERROR");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

On xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundtab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

...

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tecnologiaCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Tecnologia"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/interessiTV" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/sportCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="Sport"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tecnologiaCB"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tecnologiaCB" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/viaggiCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="Viaggi"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tecnologiaCB"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sportCB" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/casacucinaCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Casa e Cucina"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tecnologiaCB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tecnologiaCB" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/abbigliamentoCB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Abbigliamento"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/casacucinaCB"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/sportCB" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Is it possibile to fix?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you are probably setting them from a non-UI thread. Let's have a look at the function that receives the result of your DB query. Also, please include any `OnCheckedChangeListeners` you have implemented.

Comment: There are no onCheckedChangeListener. I just load a set of strings "s" or "n" from database. Then if string equals to "s" i check the CB with myCB.setChecked(true), otherwise i call myCB.setChecked(false). I do this onPostExecute() so it should be main thread...

Comment: This happens on a fragment. I have another ACTIVITY with same set of checkbox and it works correctly. I should test on another smartphone because on my emulator it works correctly.

Comment: I can't see any problem with your code. Something very strange is going on. I recommend you reduce your code to a single checkbox (e.g., `tecnologiaCB`), add a trivial `onClickListener` and `onCheckedChangedListener` (strictly for logging purposes), log all calls to `setChecked()` (along with the value of `tecnologia.equals(Utils.TRUE)`), and log the fragment lifecycle, and then post that log here (with timestamps).